# Where can I ask a "business" webmaster question?

Tags: discussion

I have just asked a question about a regular operation that belongs to a webmaster, about email/alias/lists, [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83765/when-to-create-email-addresses-and-when-email-aliases).

It was placed on hold, since it doesn't seem to be according to [the topics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that ProWebmasters are supposed to have.

I've checked the list of [all StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), but I don't find any that matches better. May be Web Applications, but that one is to ask HOW to do something in a web app, not WHICH thing to do given a good practice of a Webmaster.

I think this question should be accepted here, because in Stackoverflow for example, many questions not only ask HOW to solve a problem, but also WHICH of some already known solutions is a better suit for an specific issue, given best practices.

What do you guys think? Where should I put that question?

Comment: Important to note that the Stack Exchange sites are intended for answerable questions, for subjective questions your better of asking in various chat channels across the exchange network.

Answer (score 2):

We answer questions about running websites here.   Your question about email addresses for a business does not fit within the scope of running websites.

The best place to ask about your new business would probably be [startups.stackexchange.com](https://startups.stackexchange.com/)

Keep in mind that subjective questions are off-topic for most StackExchange sites (including webmasters).